# Showing uploaded image after successful upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, carrierwave

I am using the Carrierwave gem inside of Magnific Popup (lightbox). What I want to do is that **after** uploading a image that it will show the newly uploaded image.

Currently after a image is uploaded from the lightbox, it will continue displaying the image you were originally viewing with a "success" message that your image was successfully uploaded.

The current setup is Users click on a photo that will open a lightbox with their gallery photos. Inside the lightbox you can delete the current photo, upload a new photo, or make it your avatar.

photos.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('form#new_photo').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      file = data.files[0]
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
      $('#new_photo').append(data.context)
      data.submit()
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
    stop: (e, data) ->
      $('.upload').hide()
```

Photos controller:

```
 def create
    @photo = Photo.create(params[:photo])
    @photo.user = current_user
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

show.html.slim:

```
   -if @user.photos.present?  
        .slider_container
          h4 Photos
          a.left_arrow href="#" 
            img alt="" src="/assets/left_arrow.png" /
          ul.slider.parent-container
            = hidden_field_tag 'current_index',0
            -@user.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index|
              li class="#{index > 2 ? 'hide' : ''}"
                = link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), "#" + dom_id(photo)
                div id="#{dom_id(photo)}" class="mfp-hide"
                  center
                    = image_tag(photo.image_url(:popup))
                    - if  @user == current_user
                      = button_to('Set as Profile Image', [:avatar, photo], class: 'btn')
                      '
                      = button_to "remove", photo, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, class: 'btn'
                      = form_for Photo.new do |f|
                        = f.label :image, "Upload photos:"
                        = f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "photo[image]"
                      script#template-upload type="text/x-tmpl" 
                        .upload
                          | {%=o.name%}
                          .progress
                            .bar style=("width: 0%")
```

Comment: Well if you use ajax, respond with json containing the new pic url

Comment: you can send the image path back and append it to code html to the light box code using .html till will start showing your image if the html is in proper format

Comment: use this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6 and look at here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin You can easily change last image with js response

Comment: Since you've already iterated through all your photos, the new photo just uploaded should be there already. Do you want to show only one new photo? If that is the case, change the .slim only display the information of your @photo from controller.

Comment: I looks like an ajax call to me but in your action I see a redirect, which doesn't make sense, instead create a `action_name.js.erb` view which gets rendered instead of the redirect and you can replace the photo with the latest photo which was uploaded since you already have the `@photo` instance var available with you.

Comment: @chagel The new photo will only display if I reload the page and reopen the lightbox. So the user doesn't have to do two steps, I wanted to show the one new photo after upload.

Comment: @PamioSolanky ignore the redirect from the controller. That action is not called on since I am working inside of the lightbox. For this action to show the new photo I don't think the controller is going to be needed. Having the gallery show inside the lightbox takes away the redirect capability. So I would have to modify the photos javascript I believe.

Comment: So the problem is the result page doesn't load correctly?? Try to `render :result_view` after saving model instead of `redirect_to :back`

Comment: @chagel The problem is sending it to the result page after saving photo. Using `render :result_view` does not work. The issue is working inside of a lightbox. If I were working on a normal page I would have no issues showing the new photo after it saved.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would prefer to use http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

- complicated tasks like stop upload request.
- uploads with browsers without XHR file uploads
- async upload

It also has documentation https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API

---

If you want to do it yourself send json back with the image url.

```
var imageurl = "";
$('#inputValue').attr("src", imageurl);
```

For example i bind input value to url

```
$('#inputName').bind('input',function(){ 
   $('#inputValue').attr("src", $(this).val());
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/margusmartsepp/83w51u85/

Answer (score 0):

you are doing this very complicatedly..

this is the simple solution.Write javascript function to send the selected image using ajax.

```
<script>
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();  
   function upload_banner() 
   {
        var file = document.getElementById("file");
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file", file.files[0]);
        var files=document.getElementById('file').files;
        var file_name=files[0].name;
        //alert(file_name);
        var file_extension=file_extension_get(file_name);

        if( file_extension == "jpg" || file_extension == "JPG" || file_extension == "jpeg" || file_extension == "JPEG" || file_extension == "gif" || file_extension == "GIF" || file_extension == "png" || file_extension == "PNG" )
        {
            client.open("post", "small_img.php", true);
            client.send(formdata);  /* Send to server */    

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Wrong file format");
        }
    }
   /* Check the response status */  
   client.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
    alert(client.readyState+"sssss"+client.status);
      if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
      {

         var m=client.responseText.toString();

          $("#upload_img_view").html(m);
  upload_id();

        }
   }   
   function file_extension_get(file)
   {
        return (/[.]/.exec(file)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(file.toLowerCase()) : '';
    }

function upload_id()
    {

        var uploadid=document.getElementById('upload_id').value;
        $("#banner_id").val(uploadid);
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

In Html file write the below code to upload the file..

```
<input type="file" id="file"  name="file" onchange="upload_banner()" required name="file_create_video">             <br>

<div class="uplod-img" id="upload_img_view">
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

in php file  use the below code small_img.php

```
$path = "/var/www/upload/profile_pic/";

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
{
echo "<img src='$u' height='100%' width='100%'> <input type='hidden' id='upload_id' name='upload_id' value='$k' >";
}
```

this works for me...try it.. make some changes according to your code