# How to upload image file with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

problem when upload image MVC with ajax, i have controls_class.php content function upload_img_admin in class settings calling from page c_ajax_img.php

page c_ajax_img.php

```
include_once('controls_class.php');
$ajax_up_img = new settings;
$ajax_up_img->upload_img_admin(@$_FILES['file_upload']);
```

function upload_img_admin in class settings

```
function upload_img_admin()
{
        $dir_name=dirname(__FILE__)."/upload/";
        $path=@$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
        $name=@$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
        $size=@$_FILES['file_upload']['size'];
        $type=@$_FILES['file_upload']['type'];
        $error=@$_FILES['file_upload']['error'];  
                   ...
                   ...

if( isset($_FILES['file_upload']) )
    {
        move_uploaded_file($path,$dir_name.$name);
                      ...
                      ...
        echo "ok";

     }
     else
     {
         echo "File not found";
      }

 }
```

function ajax get data form and send to function previous for upload image

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn_upload_avatar").click(function(e) {
$('.msgerror').hide().fadeIn(1000).html(  '<div class="loading"></div>');
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "../controls/c_ajax_img.php",
cache: false,  
processData:false, 
contentType: false,
data:$("#form_up_img").serialize(),
success: function (data)
{
    if(data == 0){                  
     $('.msgerror').addClass('msgerror_in2').html(data);    
 }else{ 
    $('.msgerror').addClass('msgerror_in2').html(data); 
}
}   
});
});
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855758/showing-uploaded-image-after-successful-upload/26038832#26038832

you will get the answer from here

Comment: if you not get the answer then let me know

Comment: I did not get an answer...

Comment: in function upload_img_admin this ligne isset($_FILES['file_upload'])
sending error i think the function don't know if isset submit or no

Comment: you need to append the file first before sending to php while you are using the ajax  var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file", file.files[0]);  like this

Comment: i don't know exactly this error but when click submit the data not send and show message error "File not found" although the code ajax correctly

Comment: I thing the file you are trying to send,that file might not received by php. that is why it shows the error.First check whether the file is received or not using print_r($_FILES).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

check out this one.

Comment: function php not received file array return null

Comment: i solve the problem that error in function jquery click class `$(".btn_upload_avatar").click(function(e) ...`
must use an submit in form for sending file also php recieved this file correctly like as
`$("#form_up_img").on('submit',(function(e) ....`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help you mate.. :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#UploadForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
          $('.msgerror').hide().fadeIn(1000).html('<div class="loading"></div>');
          e.preventDefault();
          var formData = new FormData(this);
          formData.append('file', input.files[0]);

          $.ajax({
              url: '../controls/c_ajax_img.php',
              data: formData,
              contentType: false,
              type: 'POST',
              processData: false,
              success: function (data) {
                  console.log("success");
                  console.log(data);
              },
              error: function (data) {
                  console.log("error");
                  console.log(data);
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

**FYI**

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

**ProcessData** is set to false so that it prevents jQuery from automatically transforming the data into a query string

Comment: i solve the problem that error in function jquery click class `$(".btn_upload_avatar").click(function(e) ...`
must use an submit in form for sending file also php recieved this file correctly like as
`$("#form_up_img").on('submit',(function(e) ....`
thanks